# Reflected plane wave intensity air/water?

Tags: geometric-optics

Good morning.
I am evaluating this situation. A plane wave at $f=60$ MHz coming from the air affects the sea with an angle $\theta_1=80°$.
I know $n_{air}=1$ and $n_{water}=1,33$. I've applied the Snell's Law and founded $$\theta_{2}=48,5°$$
The Brewster angle is $$\theta_{c}=48,6°<\theta_{1}$$
Now I know the intensity of the incident plane wave is $$E_{0}=45\frac{mV}{m}$$And is circular polarized.

In your opinion, how can I evaluate the intensity and polarization of the reflected wave? Manu thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fresnel reflection and transmission coefficients depend upon linear polarization. Since your incident plane wave is circularly polarized, linear polarizitons at the interface are time dependent. Thus you must represent the incident circular polarized wave as a sum of [phase shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization#From_the_point_of_view_of_the_source) perpendicular and parallel polarized E-field components.

Then use the Fresnel equations to calculate reflection coefficients. Finally, superposition of these reflected linearly polarized components will give you the time dependent intensity and polarization of the reflected wave.

Also note that there is an error in the problem statement. The index of refraction of water is about 1.33 at optical wavelengths. However, it is much higher at 60 MHz. The index of refraction of water is around 9, or so, corresponding to a dielectric constant of ~80, from RF through microwave frequencies. In additon, conductivity results in significant attenuation, and will also affect the reflection coefficients. Conductivity of sea water is frequency dependent and also depends on salinity.